# javascript - output different html and js according to initial javascript condition

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with some strange login code which is proprietary code from some company. They've basically written all the login with javascript and stuck it in a weird file type which communicates with a .dll file somewhere and basically which I know not so much about.

So basically I've to work within the confines of a particular file and what I want to do is detect what width in px the users browser window is and if it's under a certain number then output certain html and javascript.

Else I output a slightly different combination of html and javascript.

In php this is no problem because I can wrap it in an if loop. But I can't do the same with javascript.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Detect browser window's width using `innerWidth`.

```
var width = window.innerWidth;

if(width < 1366 && width > 1024) {
   // under 1366, but below 1024
}
else if(width < 1024) {
   // under 1024
}
else {
   // if its bigger
}
```

`innerWidth` **doesn't include browser window's toolbars or scrollbars, if you want to include them too, use** `outerWidth` **instead**

Edit:

```
var styles;
if(width < 1366 && width > 1024) {
   styles = 'width:15px';
}
else if(width < 1024) {
   styles = 'width:20px';
}
else {
   styles = 'width:10px';
}

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<div style="' + styles + '">Hello!</div>';
```

Comment: The problem is that inside those if and else if loops I need to out put LOTS of html and javascript. How can I output a bunch of html and javascript which will be different depending on the browser width

Comment: Using variables. then you just need to have one html block, and you can set those variables depending on the browser's width.